unable to recognize my inputs in python plotty - dash
dash_app = dash.Dash(__name__)
dash_app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.P("Range: ", style={'margin-right': '10px'}),
        dcc.Input(id='user-min-strike', type='number', value=5600, style={'margin-right': '10px'}),
        dcc.Input(id='user-max-strike', type='number', value=5800),
        dcc.Input(id='user-minutes', type='number', value=100),
    ], style={'display': 'flex', 'align-items': 'center', 'margin-bottom': '20px'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph', config={'displayModeBar': False}),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=2*1000,  # Update every 2 seconds
        n_intervals=0
    )
])

my callback:
@dash_app.callback(
    Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
     Input('user-min-strike', 'value'),
     Input('user-max-strike', 'value'),
     Input('user-minutes', 'value')
     ])

i get this error:
lambda ind: inputs_state[ind], inputs_state_indices
IndexError: list index out of range

i got into dash code and print the number of inputs right after they get them from the body, it only includes one, the interval
even though they appear in the webpage
print the body from dash code:
{'output': 'live-update-graph.figure', 'outputs': {'id': 'live-update-graph', 'property': 'figure'}, 'inputs': [{'id': 'interval-component', 'property': 'n_intervals', 'value': 148}], 'changedPropIds': ['interval-component.n_intervals'], 'parsedChangedPropsIds': ['interval-component.n_intervals']}


and yes, chatgpt isn't helping, he think my code is correct, i tried gemini also, nothing works

I think a function is required below callback if I understood the requirement correctly.

The relevant code is missing, edit your post and add the callback function (which should be defined just below its decorator @dash_app.callback(...).

The error you're encountering is likely due to the fact that your input components are not being correctly
rendered or their IDs are not properly recognized when the callback is triggered
in Dash, the dcc.Input components need to be fully rendered and available on the page before their
values can be accessed in the callback. Since the error suggests that only the
interval-component is being detected, there are a few potential causes and solutions
check for errors in browser devtools
ensure the dcc.Interval component is outside the div that might affect how it updates try placing at same level as graph
use state instead of input for static fields like the user input values
the interval is the only part that’s dynamic and should remain as an input
@dash_app.callback(
    Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')],
    [State('user-min-strike', 'value'),
     State('user-max-strike', 'value'),
     State('user-minutes', 'value')]

